# Exception in thread "main java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I keep getting an `error message` from the output

```
Exception in thread "main java.util.InputMismatchException        

    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at test1.TC1.main(TC1.java:11)
```

but at the top it doesn't have any errors

```
package test1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TC1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double name, age, answer;
        Scanner IN = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Whats yor name?");
        name = IN.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        age = IN.nextDouble();
        answer = age + name;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Change type of you variables to `String` instead of `double`, and use [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public class TC1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name, age, answer;
        Scanner IN = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Whats yor name?");
        name = IN.next();
        System.out.println("How old are you?");
        age = IN.next();
        answer = age + name;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`name` is actually a variable of type double. But maybe you are asking for the name which should be of type string.

Change the type of name and use  `name = IN.nextLine();`

Comment: i also have another problem that his guy named 19 isn't really helping me since i'm a begginer at this java thing...

Comment: link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111392/the-method-gamerender-is-undefined-for-the-type-gamepanel

Comment: it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

This exception will be thrown when you will give **non-numeric** input.

In your case you have declared **name** as a **double**, and I am quite sure that you are entering a **non-numeric** value in it, say Travis or Lita whatever :)

So either declare name as String and use IN.next() or try entering a numeric value :)